# how can i call value from methods?

Tags: java

in my code i have Numbers from 0 to 10 , i am use random methods ,

so i want calculate the sum of them , how can i done by use mehods ?

note : i will use it in GUI ( JFrame )

```
  public static int random1 ()
 {
   Random n = new Random () ;
   int x = n.nextInt( 10 ) + 0 ;

   return x ;

}

public static int random2 ()
{
   Random n = new Random () ;
   int y = n.nextInt( 10 ) + 0 ;

   return y;

}

public void sum ()
{
    int result = x.random1() + y.random2() ;
}
```

Comment: suppose just use as `int result = random1() + random2() ;`

Comment: `x.random1()` says that you have some object named `x` and you want to call _that object's_ method named `random1` ...  you don't need the `x.` and `y.` prefixes on your calls to random1 and random2 (and, as other's have pointed out, you don't need two methods that each do the same thing.

Comment: but what I told you is just a general example, I will put the random numbers inside the JLabel then ask the user to place the answer within JTextField then I will check whether the user answer is correct or not, only I'm sorry I did not tell you these details

Answer (score 0):

You just need one `random` method, and use it: `result = random()+random()`

Comment: this is it's clear for me , but the problem when i want ask the user what is the sum of number , when the user write the result , i want to check if it's correct answer or not :(

Comment: You need some thing like: 
`System.out.println("Please enter the sum: ");`
`String answer = input.nextLine();`
then check: `if (result == Integer.valueOf(answer))`

Comment: Great, but what I told you is just a general example
I will put the random numbers inside the JLabel then ask the user to place the answer within JTextField then I will check whether the user answer is correct or not, only
I'm sorry I did not tell you these details

Comment: Then just add add the `JTextField` as your demand, then get the value from that `JTextField` to check it. Google for tutorial about using `JTextField` if you not familiar with it!

Comment: Thank you, I know how to use it
But the real question is how to call the variable from JLabel ^ـ^

Comment: `String x = jLable.getText()` it will return a String, then convert to int for compare like: `Integer.valueOf(x)`

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = random1() + random2();
```

although both of your methods do exactly the same thing, so get rid of the second method, rename the first method random and then

```
int result = random() + random();
```

Comment: this is it's clear for me , but the problem when i want ask the user what is the sum of number , when the user write the result , i want to check if it's correct answer or not :(